# XPath Issue: Not able to click on checkbox

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I have one HTML form where I need to click on checkbox but somehow it is not able to click on checkbox and instead it click on link

HTML Element - When checkbox is not clicked

```
<div class="form-group">
   <input id="chkTermAndCondition" type="checkbox">
   <label for="chkTermAndCondition">
      I have read and agree to the
      <a id="lnkTermsAndCondition" href="javascrip:void(0);">terms and conditions.</a>
   </label>
</div>
```

HTML Element - After checkbox is clicked

[image: HTML Element - After checkbox is clicked]

XPAth Used but not working and clicking on "link"

```
//*[@for='chkTermAndCondition'] - click on link
//*[@id='chkTermAndCondition'] - This doesn't work
//div[@id='sellerInformationDiv']/div[3]/div/label - click on link
```

Both the above xpath is not clicking on checkbox

Comment: In spite of use click, maybe you can try to send keys SPACE

Comment: //input[@id='chkTermAndCondition']//following-sibling::label OR //input[@id='chkTermAndCondition']/following-sibling::label  can you check with above x-path.

Comment: didn't work, it opens the link only which is in <a> tag

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try below code:

```
IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
js.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", driver.FindElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='chkTermAndCondition']"));
```

Comment: this is also not working, as the checkbox is in <label> tag but when using xpath of label then it clicks on link which is associated to <a> tag

Comment: Can you share complete HTML of page ( Not image ) as i tried with first HTML code you shared and it selected checkbox. As you can see there was one input tag for checkbox just above <label> tag. Also what error you got when you tried with above xpath shared by me?

Comment: it doesn't clicks the checkbox, actually i label there is "before" and then "a" tag..so everytime we use label'selector and do click then it clicks the link of "a" tag

Comment: Try with JavaScript executioner I have shared in code.

Comment: @Chandler Please up vote as it will help other facing similar issues. Cheers Buddy :)